# Tree like HTML table with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have an HTML table with tree like structure like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/249e80tz/)

Now `text1_2` is sum of values in `text1_2_1` and `text1_2_2`. Similarly, `text1` is sum of `text1_1` and `text1_2`.

I want to use knockout to do data binding to this table and send the json array to the server for saving. I have to create the json object for each cell rather than row .  I am not getting idea on how to implement this.

```
{
  "Lvl1Desc": "text1",
  "Lv2Desc": Null,
  "Lv3Desc": Null,
  "Lv4Desc": Null,
  "quarter": "Q",
  "quarterId": 1,
  "Year": "year1",
  "Amount": 2200
}
```

if it doesnot have quarter like for year 2

then object should be

```
{
  "Lvl1Desc": "text1",
  "Lv2Desc": Null,
  "Lv3Desc": Null,
  "Lv4Desc": Null,
  "quarter": "Y",
  "quarterId": Null,
  "Year": "year2",
  "Amount": 2200
}
```

Appreciate any help in this

Comment: Have you been through the Knockout tutorial? http://learn.knockoutjs.com/
You will want to model the structure of your application in a viewmodel.

Comment: I have a couple questions: 1) Is the idea that the user populates the data and then you capture it and send it to the server? 2) Will the user be allowed to add rows and / or next rows inside of other nodes?